# Open XML SDK: How to retrieve parent OpenXmlPart from a TypedOpenXmlCompositeElement?

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

Is it possible to retrieve the parent `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPart` instance for a `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.TypedOpenXmlCompositeElement`?

For instance, in the code below, I want to obtain the `SlidePart` (a derived class of `OpenXmlPart`) instance for the `Shape` (a derived class of `TypedOpenXmlCompositeElement`):

```cs
using P = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;

public static void GetSlidePart()
{
    var presDoc = PresentationDocument.Open("test.pptx", false);
    P.Shape pShape = presDoc.PresentationPart!.SlideParts.First().Slide.CommonSlideData!.ShapeTree!.Elements<P.Shape>().First();
    //...
    
    SlidePart parentSlidePartOfPShape = // pShape...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@adam-shakhabov I've made a change in the OpenXmlPartRootElement class that allows access to the OpenXmlPart property. With this change, the following code should work for what you're trying to do:

```
OpenXmlPartRootElement partRoot = pShape.Ancestors<OpenXmlPartRootElement>().First();

if (partRoot.OpenXmlPart is null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("partRoot is null");
    return;
}

OpenXmlPart part = partRoot.OpenXmlPart;
```

I mentioned you in the [PR on github](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/pull/1543) which has already been merged into main and will be in v3.0. Let me know if you have any questions or follow-up on this.